# Tkinter input from entry widget inside a function

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have a program where I take input from the user from entry widget and it does a function based on input. Now what has to be done so that I can take input from user inside the function?

For example

- if user types calculate in the entry widget.
- Goes to calculate()
- Inside the function it needs the input of 2 numbers from user. How can I get these from user using the same entry widget used before.

[image: 1]

Comment: where exactly do you plan to return that value? also you should post code in your question and as text (and format accordingly), the simplest seems to be using simpledialog and ask for numbers

Comment: Have you done any research or worked through a tkinter tutorial? Tkinter tutorials will cover the fundamentals of creating widgets and getting values from them.

Comment: i am in the process of learning

Answer (score 1):

This is about as simple as it can get (not the most theme matching way but it works):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button, simpledialog


def calc():
    x = simpledialog.askinteger('Calculation', 'Enter x')
    y = simpledialog.askinteger('Calculation', 'Enter Y')
    print(x + y)


root = Tk()

Button(root, text='Calculate', command=calc).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Used a Button for simplicity but you should understand how to do this the way you were doing. Also where do you plan to return that value? Certainly can't be returned back to the `command` argument or the like, depends on how you have it set up (if you assign the returned value to some variable then probably fine)

Also:
I strongly suggest following [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Function and variable names should be in `snake_case`, class names in `CapitalCase`. Don't have space around `=` if it is used as a part of keyword argument (`func(arg='value')`) but have space around `=` if it is used for assigning a value (`variable = 'some value'`). Have space around operators (`+-/` etc.: `value = x + y`(except here `value += x + y`)). Have two blank lines around function and class declarations.

Comment: yes buttons can be used....
but as i said i need to input from entry widget....i have many functions like calculate()...so i need to get input what to be performed...like a bot..thank you

Comment: @Sandy yeah, I understand, I was just demonstrating the call to function and what it does, simplest way was using a button for me, you just have to call this function from wherever you need

Comment: Thanks i tried using buttons but it just skipped it and directly does the process...ending up giving error

Comment: i got it to work ....thanks man...previously i did a small error and thanks for the tips too

Comment: @Sandy hard to tell what happened without your code, you probably did sth like `command=func()` when it should have been `command=func`, if you need to pass arguments then use `command=lambda: func(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Yes i did the error what you exactly said.... i am just learning and these errors help me learn better... :)

Comment: would like to show the code...but its too longg to send here

Comment: @Sandy if the issues is fixed then no need for the code anymore, if you have other questions tho then ask another question but before read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

It is simple.
Code:

```
def calculate():
    num1 = int(input("Enter First Number: "))
    
    num2 = int(input("Enter Second Number: "))

    x = num1,num2
    addition = sum(x)

    print(f"The sum of the two given numbers is {addition} ")
    
calculate()
```